# When will Azure (US West) support small VM websites?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, service-not-available

I'm currently unable to create a small dedicated website. I'm getting this error:

**Not enough available reserved instance servers to satisfy this request.**

[image]

Anyone from Azure able to comment on when we can expect this size to be available in the US West region?

Comment: What did customer support say?

Comment: Actually if you go to the support page, it says post here (on stack overflow and tag with "Azure").

Comment: It's not a natural fit for the site, as the answer will expire in a period of time, and the general public won't know the internal plans for deploying new servers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an external website and not about developing for it

Comment: Just now I tried to create a Standard Website in West US datacenter with Small instance. I got it successful. Probably you need to retry after particular time. It might be a transient error what you have encountered.

Comment: @ramiramilu - thanks for the update. This was happening for a couple days in a row. I ended up just moving my instance to the East US region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to post this on Azure Forum - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/forums/

Usually Azure doesn't provide any time estimates for resource availability.

Consider deploying to a different DC, latency difference may not be much different.